# Parse a dataframe and a fastafile

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I simply have a dataframe and a fasta file and what I need to do is only to keep row in the dataframe (or creat a new one) if the seq_id is in my fasta file.

Here is an exemple:

dataframe:

```
seq_1    seq_2      GC       Length
seq1     seq2       68       15561
seq4     seq3       89       567
seq9     seq90      45       789
seq97    seq43      56       458
seq45    seq9       67       900
```

fastafile:

```
>seq9 
ACTG
>seq97 
ACTG
>seq1
ACTG
```

and get a new df such:

```
seq_1    seq_2      GC       Length
seq1     seq2       68       15561
seq9     seq90      45       789
seq97    seq43      56       458
```

Thanks for you help :)

Comment: What have you tried already and why didn't it work? Do you want us to solve 1. reading in data from a 'fastfile' (what is a fastafile...?) and 2. how to filter your dataframe based on the read input for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read lines in a `fastafile` into list of string `fasta_lines`
2. Filter sequence names from `fasta_lines` by `seq_list = [s for s in fasta_lines if s.startswith('>')]`
3. Filter rows in your dataframe with the `seq_list` filter: `dataframe = dataframe[dataframe['seq_1'].isin(seq_list) || dataframe['seq_2'].isin(seq_list)]`
4. Check if `dataframe.shape[0] == 0` so there are no rows in your new dataframe append a new row according to your logic of parsing a `fastafile`

This answer needs some code checks maybe after you specify the logics for processing the `fastafile`.

Comment: there should be `[s[1:] for s in ...` when reading in the fasta-data, otherwise there wouldn't be any matching because of the imported '>'-sign (cannot edit, because edits have to be more than 6 characters long...)